# Error in saving the edited record VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I'm using the `.EndEdit` and the `.Update` for saving my records in datagridview. I'm also using access database which has 145 fields in one table. I'm keep getting a `an unhandled exception in...` error with an additional message `Too many fields defined` when saving an edited record. It is working fine when adding/saving new records. Is my field too many? I've read that the access has 255 fields limit per table...

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Info

Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form


Private Sub bday1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bday.ValueChanged
    Dim d1, d2 As Date
    Dim days, months, years As Long

    d1 = bday.Value.ToShortDateString
    d2 = Now.ToShortDateString

    years = Year(d1)
    months = Month(d1)
    days = d1.Day

    years = Year(d2) - years
    months = Month(d2) - months
    days = d2.Day - days

    If Math.Sign(days) = -1 Then
        days = 30 - Math.Abs(days)
        months = months - 1
    End If

    If Math.Sign(months) = -1 Then
        months = 12 - Math.Abs(months)
        years = years - 1
    End If

    age.Text = years.ToString
    'TextBox2.Text = months.ToString
    'TextBox3.Text = days.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub add1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add1.Click
    comname2.Enabled = True
    posi2.Enabled = True
    deptm2.Enabled = True
    tm2.Enabled = True
    reason2.Enabled = True
    add2.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub add2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add2.Click
    comname3.Enabled = True
    posi3.Enabled = True
    deptm3.Enabled = True
    tm3.Enabled = True
    reason3.Enabled = True
    add3.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub add3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add3.Click
    comname4.Enabled = True
    posi4.Enabled = True
    deptm4.Enabled = True
    tm4.Enabled = True
    reason4.Enabled = True
    add4.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub add4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add4.Click
    comname5.Enabled = True
    posi5.Enabled = True
    deptm5.Enabled = True
    tm5.Enabled = True
    reason5.Enabled = True
    add5.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub add5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add5.Click
    comname6.Enabled = True
    posi6.Enabled = True
    deptm6.Enabled = True
    tm6.Enabled = True
    reason6.Enabled = True
    add6.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub add6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add6.Click
    comname7.Enabled = True
    posi7.Enabled = True
    deptm7.Enabled = True
    tm7.Enabled = True
    reason7.Enabled = True
    add7.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub add7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add7.Click
    comname8.Enabled = True
    posi8.Enabled = True
    deptm8.Enabled = True
    tm8.Enabled = True
    reason8.Enabled = True
    add8.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub add8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add8.Click
    comname9.Enabled = True
    posi9.Enabled = True
    deptm9.Enabled = True
    tm9.Enabled = True
    reason9.Enabled = True
    add9.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub add9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add9.Click
    comname10.Enabled = True
    posi10.Enabled = True
    deptm10.Enabled = True
    tm10.Enabled = True
    reason10.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Info_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_Employees__RecordDataSet._employees__record' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Employees__recordTableAdapter.Fill(Me._Employees__RecordDataSet._employees__record)


End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add.Click
    EmployeesRecordBindingSource.AddNew()
    TextBox1.Text = getAutoId
    enableall()

End Sub

Private Function getAutoId() As Integer
    If Me.DataGridView.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        getAutoId = 1
    Else
        getAutoId = Me.DataGridView.Rows(Me.DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(0).Value + 0
    End If
End Function

Private Sub btnReg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReg.Click
    On Error GoTo dito
    Dim D1, D2, D3, D4 As Date

    D1 = bday.Value.ToShortDateString
    D2 = Now.ToShortDateString
    D3 = date1.Value.ToShortDateString
    D4 = date1.Value.ToShortDateString

    If D1 >= D2 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Birthday must not be less than or equal to current date!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        bday.Value = Now.Date
    ElseIf fname.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert First Name Please!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    ElseIf lname.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Last Name Please!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    ElseIf mi.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Middle Initial Name Please!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    ElseIf address.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Address Please!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    ElseIf age.Text <= 17 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Age must be 18yrs. and above.", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    ElseIf sex.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Choose Sex Please!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    ElseIf contact.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Contact Number Please!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    ElseIf dept1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Department Please!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    ElseIf pos1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Position Please!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    ElseIf civil.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Choose Civil Status Please!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    Else
        EmployeesRecordBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Employees__recordTableAdapter.Update(Me._Employees__RecordDataSet._employees__record)
        MessageBox.Show("Record Save!", "Success!")
        disableall()

    End If
dito:
    Exit Sub

End Sub

Private Sub civil_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If civil.SelectedItem = "Married" Then
        spouse.Enabled = True

    ElseIf civil.SelectedItem = "Widowed" Then
        spouse.Enabled = True

    ElseIf civil.SelectedItem = "Legally Separated" Then
        spouse.Enabled = True

    ElseIf civil.SelectedItem = "Anulled" Then
        spouse.Enabled = True

    Else
        spouse.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    enableall()

End Sub
Private Sub enableall()
    lname.Enabled = True
    fname.Enabled = True
    mi.Enabled = True
    bday.Enabled = True
    sex.Enabled = True
    natio.Enabled = True
    address.Enabled = True
    contact.Enabled = True
    father.Enabled = True
    mother.Enabled = True
    tin.Enabled = True
    sss.Enabled = True
    pagibig.Enabled = True
    phh.Enabled = True
    stat.Enabled = True
    dept1.Enabled = True
    pos1.Enabled = True
    rm.Enabled = True
    date1.Enabled = True
    civil.Enabled = True
    termiresi.Enabled = True
    date2.Enabled = True
    heduc.Enabled = True
    elem.Enabled = True
    y1.Enabled = True
    hs.Enabled = True
    y2.Enabled = True
    col.Enabled = True
    y3.Enabled = True
    deg.Enabled = True
    pdeg.Enabled = True
    ts.Enabled = True
    y4.Enabled = True
    other.Enabled = True
    childno.Enabled = True
    childone.Enabled = True
    childtwo.Enabled = True
    childthree.Enabled = True
    childfour.Enabled = True
    childfive.Enabled = True
    childsix.Enabled = True
    childseven.Enabled = True
    childeight.Enabled = True
    childnine.Enabled = True
    btnReg.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub disableall()

    lname.Enabled = False
    fname.Enabled = False
    mi.Enabled = False
    bday.Enabled = False
    sex.Enabled = False
    natio.Enabled = False
    address.Enabled = False
    contact.Enabled = False
    father.Enabled = False
    mother.Enabled = False
    tin.Enabled = False
    sss.Enabled = False
    pagibig.Enabled = False
    phh.Enabled = False
    stat.Enabled = False
    dept1.Enabled = False
    pos1.Enabled = False
    rm.Enabled = False
    date1.Enabled = False
    civil.Enabled = False
    termiresi.Enabled = False
    date2.Enabled = False
    heduc.Enabled = False
    elem.Enabled = False
    y1.Enabled = False
    hs.Enabled = False
    y2.Enabled = False
    col.Enabled = False
    y3.Enabled = False
    deg.Enabled = False
    pdeg.Enabled = False
    ts.Enabled = False
    y4.Enabled = False
    other.Enabled = False
    Add.Enabled = True
    btnReg.Enabled = False
    childno.Enabled = False
    childone.Enabled = False
    childtwo.Enabled = False
    childthree.Enabled = False
    childfour.Enabled = False
    childfive.Enabled = False
    childsix.Enabled = False
    childseven.Enabled = False
    childeight.Enabled = False
    childnine.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    childno.Enabled = True
    childone.Enabled = True
    childtwo.Enabled = True
    childthree.Enabled = True
    childfour.Enabled = True
    childfive.Enabled = True
    childsix.Enabled = True
    childseven.Enabled = True
    childeight.Enabled = True
    childnine.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    On Error GoTo dire
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete Record", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        EmployeesRecordBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
        Employees__recordTableAdapter.Update(Me._Employees__RecordDataSet._employees__record)
    End If


dire:
    Exit Sub
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: 145 fields? Make me doubt about the normalization of your table. Can you post your code?

Comment: _"The internal column count that Microsoft Access uses to track the number of fields in the table has reached 255, even though you may have fewer than 255 fields in the table. This can happen because Microsoft Access does not change the internal column count when you delete a field. Microsoft Access also creates a new field (increasing the internal column count by 1) for every field whose properties you modify."_ according to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/128221)

Comment: I edit my post and put my code... I created new database without deleting or editing my fields....

Comment: Yes, sir. I've read that. The solution there is to compact and repair the database to repair the database. I did that when I edited / deleted some field in my old database. But I'm having the same problem...

Comment: Read more about [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). It could help you a lot. There are no other solutions since that is their database's limit. All you can do now is to _normalize_ your table.

Comment: Sure, sir. I'll read about it :) Thank you for your help, sir :)

Comment: No problem. The count of the fields in one table is quiet troublesome to maintain. Throwing everything in one table doesn't look neat in my opinion. Try segregating it with different tables and have some keys (most of the time, these are IDs) so that you can have proper _table relationships_.

Comment: Sure, sir :) Can I message you in gmail for further questions? I have so many problems that I can't find in google....

Comment: Pinoy ka di ba? May FB ka? Dun na lang tayo mag-usap. Iwan mo na lang e-mail mo dito. Company e-mail kasi active e-mail ko ngayon.

Comment: Opo sir :) Pwede nyo po kong mahanap: mar_roe17@yahoo.com.ph yung gamit ko pong email sa fb. Marvin Baltazar Bitantes po name ko :)

Comment: Any news or progress?

Comment: I sorted my tables in database. I now have 5 tables. I put ID in each table and connect it to one another to produce a relationship. The 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 tables have `One-to-One relationship` while the 4-5 tables has `One-to-many relationship`. Is this okay?

Comment: Looking great! :)

Comment: I will now proceed to coding. Is it the same in my way of connecting to database? I mean, the `Add Data Source` thing? :)

Comment: When you insert, of course your gonna have multiple insert statements for each of your newly created tables.

Comment: I will be back this afternoon after I tested it in my sample project. Hope it works :) Thank you for the help and advice sir :)

Comment: Goodluck, bro!!

Comment: Sir, when saving records, the only record that will be shown is the records in table 1. Records in table 2 is not recorded or not showing. I used `.EndEdit` and `.Update` command. I also used `.AddNew` in adding rows in both table. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Post a new question regarding that. Include the details on your _Insert_ query and the events on where you trigger your saving. I'll check it later. Or if someone answers it, the better. I'm currently breaking my head also.

Comment: Sure sir :) Thank you and sorry for disturbing :)

Comment: Where's your post?

Comment: Oh sorry sir. I was busy solving it by trying the `INSERT` command.... I'll post it maybe later or tomorrow if I don't succeed in trying :)